# Options Not Showing In Android Studio Flutter Bulb

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Recently I’ve installed all the software for my app development projects and what i see is only two options are showing upon clicking yellow bulb
Options are:
1)create new scratch file from selection
2)adjust code style settings
Options that are not showing were:
Wrap with widget
Wrap with container etc

Comment: Have you tried some code on the dart file?